# Website links work on Desktop, not on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my site: www.apologeticscentral.co.za

The menu links works on desktop, but not on mobile. Also when simulating the mobile site using Chrome developer tools, the menu links work as well.

On mobile, the menu links work when using force touch (on iPhone), and when I hold it down and say open, it works as well. But a simple click does nothing. Any ideas what the cause may be?

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="links">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="apologia/index.html">Apologia</a></li>                         
        <li><a href="argument/index.html">Argument</a></li>
        <li><a href="articles/index.html">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="bible/index.html">Bible</a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQ/index.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="icons">
        <li><a target="blank" href="https://twitter.com/ApologeticsC" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
        <li><a target="blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/apologeticscentral" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a target="blank" class="icon alt fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to include the code that works on the desktop, but not mobile. Not the whole site, just what work and what doesn't.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: When using developer tools, and simulating the mobile site, there is no problem as well. Adding code now.

Comment: Your links are not correctly formatted. Either use the full url apologeticscentral.co.za/about.html or /about.html, not about.html only. Then it works.

Comment: No luck sorry @NathanielFlick

Comment: You should update the links, I reckon, as they are incorrect in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that Angular Material was conflicting with my CSS. I created a separate module and I did not include material in that module, then it worked fine.